# How to add coloured line before caption?

Tags: captions

I need to add a coloured line before my caption; this is what I used:

```
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{\hrulefill #1  #2 #3}
\captionsetup[figure]{format=myformat}
```

but the figure turns out to be line this:

[image]

and not a horinzontal line which what I want

2) I want the line to be coloured RGB [152 204 204] with thickness about the same as \top rule. Can anyone show me how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by *coloured line before caption*? A vertical line in front of *Figure*, or a horizontal line above the caption? It would help us if you provided the complete code of a small document that defines and uses the caption (just add it to your question), as well as a picture (or a precise verbal description) of how it should look like.

Comment: @gernot horizontal line above caption with different colour instead of black

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the caption format as

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\newcommand\myhrulefill[1]{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height#1\hfill\kern0pt}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{{\color[RGB]{152,204,204}\myhrulefill{0.08em}}\\#1#2#3}
\captionsetup[figure]{format=myformat}
```

All that was missing in your code was the line end after `\hrulefill`. The argument of `\myhrulefill` is the thickness of the line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\newcommand\myhrulefill[1]{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height#1\hfill\kern0pt}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{{\color[RGB]{152,204,204}\myhrulefill{0.08em}}\\#1#2#3}
\captionsetup[figure]{format=myformat}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Schematic diagram to visualise the flow of the experiment bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\color[RGB]{152,204,204}`... and `\toprule` probably refers to the [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package's `\toprule`, which is set using `\heavyrulewidth` (from the package), or `0.08em`.

Comment: @Werner Thanks! I overlooked that there was a second question, too.