# Formatting a line between a Figure and a caption

Tags: floats, formatting

I was perusing through thesis and came across the following formatting (as shown in the picture attached) where there is a line separating the figure and its caption.

I really like this formatting, but have no idea how to actually reproduce it. I am currently using the following preamble,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Formatted such that there exists a line between the figure and the caption.]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows which documentclass you are using? The `caption` package might be a starting point.

Comment: have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343070/36296

Comment: You're welcome! Does the linked answer solve your problem?

Comment: Indeed, it works great!!!

Comment: Good to hear! I suggested to mark this question as duplicate of the linked one. This way future users with the same problem, that find your question, will see the link and know where the solution is.